# Send request and get response from php server for android

Tags: php, android, json, url

I'm trying to send a http request to php server in format of query string (eg: url?values) to server and get the response on my android device.
But `HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(URL);` is throwing an exception.

Note: I have to send only in this format else please advice the php code that how server programmer can read the request like:

```
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(URL);
JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
try {
    // JSON data:
    json.put("PN", "Products");
    json.put("position", "5th");

    JSONArray postjson=new JSONArray();
    postjson.put(json);

    // Post the data:

    httppost.setHeader("json",json.toString());
    HttpParams ht=httppost.getParams().setParameter("jsonpost",postjson);
    String s=ht.toString();
    // Execute HTTP Post Request

    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
```

Comment: What exception is it throwing?

Comment: It's throwing exception  invokespecial java.lang.RuntimeException(java.lang.String)

Comment: Also an ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8647):at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)

Comment: If you could add the whole stack trace to your question that would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

try replacing json.tostring() here:

```
httppost.setHeader("json",json.toString());
```

replace it with "application/json"